# Do the terms 'sample complexity' and 'sample efficiency' mean the same thing in RL context

Tags: reinforcement-learning, comparison, terminology, sample-efficiency, sample-complexity

For example, the the paper [Soft Actor-Critic:Off-Policy Maximum Entropy Deep Reinforcement Learning with a Stochastic Actor](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1801.01290.pdf), both terms are mentioned but without explaining. I have seen them in other places as well but in different contexts. So I am confused because in this paper they are seemingly used in an interchangeable manner.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The **sample complexity** is defined precisely in [computational learning theory](https://ai.stackexchange.com/q/20355/2444), which studies learning from a theoretical standpoint (like theoretical physics for physics).

Here's a definition taken from the book [Understanding Machine Learning: From Theory to Algorithms](https://www.cs.huji.ac.il/%7Eshais/UnderstandingMachineLearning/understanding-machine-learning-theory-algorithms.pdf).

> The function $m_\mathcal{H} : (0, 1)^2 \rightarrow N$ determines the sample complexity of learning $\mathcal{H}$: that is, **how many examples are required to guarantee a *probably approximately correct* solution**. The sample complexity is a function of the accuracy ($\epsilon$) and
> confidence ($\delta$) parameters. It also depends on properties of the hypothesis class $\mathcal{H}$ – for example, for a finite class we showed that the sample complexity depends on log the size of $\mathcal{H}$.

The intuitive definition of the sample complexity is **in bold**.

To understand why $m_\mathcal{H}$ determines the sample complexity, you should learn about the PAC learning model, where PAC stands for *probably approximately correct*, which is defined in the same book - see definition 3.1.

Once you are familiar with the concepts of hypothesis class, accuracy $\epsilon$ (not the accuracy you may be used to), confidence $\delta$ (not the confidence you may be used to), and other ideas described in the same book, then, for example, the equation in *corollary 3.2* of the same book will make sense to you. Here's corollary 3.2 for completeness.

> Every finite hypothesis class is PAC learnable with sample
> complexity
>
> $m_\mathcal{H}(\epsilon, \delta) \leq  \left \lceil \frac{\log (|\mathcal{H}|/\delta)}{\epsilon} \right \rceil$

In this equation, $|\mathcal{H}|$ (the size of the hypothesis class $\mathcal{H}$), $\epsilon$ and $\delta$ are numbers, so $m_\mathcal{H}(\epsilon, \delta)$ is also number. So, $m_\mathcal{H}(\epsilon, \delta)$, the sample complexity of $\mathcal{H}$, is bounded from above by that expression $\left \lceil \frac{\log (|\mathcal{H}|/\delta)}{\epsilon} \right \rceil$.

The **sample efficiency** is a similar notion, which is, as far as I know, more commonly used in reinforcement learning. [This answer](https://ai.stackexchange.com/a/21996/2444) describes it well.

It's possible that, in the context of RL, people use these 2 terms interchangeably, i.e. when they use the term *sample complexity*, they refer to the *sample efficiency* described in [this](https://ai.stackexchange.com/a/21996/2444) or [this](https://ai.stackexchange.com/a/5295/2444) answers.

[The famous RL book](http://www.incompleteideas.net/book/RLbook2020.pdf) also defines the concept of the sample complexity to measure the exploration efficiency of an RL algorithm

> A definition of the sample complexity of exploration for a reinforcement learning algorithm is the **number of time steps in which the algorithm does not select near-optimal actions**

So, the ideas of sample complexity or efficiency are similar, both in RL and learning theory, but the precise definitions may differ. You should take context into account.

Comment: Very comprehensive answer. Thank you so much